# Create Loop from Existing Code

Tags: python, for-loop

Below is a code that will open a .csv file and insert a header at line '0'

What I want to do is create a loop so that I can point the code at a directory and loop through each file one by one.  Each file in the directory have 23 million lines and I am running into memory errors when I try to write the loop. The code below works fine for a single text file.

```
    import os

    L = list()
    f = open(in.txt, 'rb')
    for line in f.readlines():
             L.append(line)
    L.insert(0,"x,y\n")
    f.close()

    f1 = open(in.txt, 'wb')
    for line in xrange(len(L)):
            f1.write(L[line])

            f1.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, don't do that. Open the new file, write out the header, use [`shutil.copyfileobj()`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj) to copy the contents, then rename.

Comment: +1, A better solution to the problem than mine.  But not helpfull enough to stop the OP from improperly using readlines.

Answer (score 1):

Readlines reads the entire file in to memory.  Do this to read the file one line at atime.

```
for line in f:
    L.append(line)
```

You don't need to use xrange in the second loop. You can loop directly over the array.  You are incorrectly closing the file inside the loop.  Try:

```
for line in L:
    f1.write(line)
f1.close()
```

**EDIT**

Ignacio provided a much better solution to the problem, but in general, you should use my solution for iterating over lines in a file.